# Flask on PyCharm - ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pycharm

I am trying to create and run a simple flask server on PyCharm community 2019.3

I work with python 3.7.
I used venv to create the project.
Flask was installed like this:

```
(venv) pip install flask
```

from the pycharm terminal on c:\Users\Damo\PycharmProjects\myflaskproj\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\

In the Edit configuration I created a new python run configuration.

I used the above path as my **script path** and set "run" as the **parameters**.

I added FLASK_APP=myflaskproj.py to the environment parameters.
Finally I set C:\Users\Damo\PycharmProjects\myflaskproj as my working directory.

[image]

When I run the project, I get :

```
C:\Users\Damo\PycharmProjects\myflaskproj\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Damo/PycharmProjects/myflaskproj/venv/Lib/site-packages/flask run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Damo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\Users\Damo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:/Users/Damo/PycharmProjects/myflaskproj/venv/Lib/site-packages/flask\__main__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .cli import main
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Where do I go wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show the full traceback

Comment: Added. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete answer...

[Running flask server configuration for PyCharm](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#pycharm-integration)